# xades4j.utils.XadesProfileResolutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException SoapUI

Tags: java, soapui, xades4j

On a latest SoapUI version 5.6.0 I have a problem with signing documents.
log : xades4j.utils.XadesProfileResolutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
java jdk 14.0.2
libraries: xades4j-1.5.1,xmlsec-2.0.9
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of xades4j includes the proper JAXB dependencies.

Info on alternatives with earlier versions here: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/212